# ¿COMO SUBIR ARCHIVOS A FIREBASE STORAGE DESDE VB.NET?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, firebase

**Contexto:**
Estoy haciendo una implementación (clase.vb) en visual basic .net donde tengo una lista de rutas de archivo, los cuales quiero subir a **FireBase Storage**. Buscando en la documentación de Firebase no veo ninguna plataforma que apoyo con ello, pensaba utilizar el **"SDK de Firebase Admin"** pero veo que no incluye los metodos para utilizar **"el storage"**.

¿Alguien sabe como pueod utilizar Firebase storage desde visual .net?

De antemano muchas gracias
Saludos.

[image: Plataformas de Firebase]

Comment: El SDK de Admin tiene soporte para `Node`, `Java`, `Python` y `go`, por lo que debes crear un servicio que recoja la información de tus archivos y los envíe a Firebase, usualmente se crea una aplicación en `Node.js` a la cual se le realizan las peticiones con la información necesaria de tus archivos. Para ello debes generar una clave privada desde >configuracion>cuentas de servicio e incluirla en tu app como indica la documentación oficial. Revisa la documentacion oficial para usar Firebase Storage con el SDK de Admin:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start?authuser=0#node.js

Comment: Hola @MarcosF gracias por tu comentario, pero lo que necesito es utilizar **FireBase Storage** del lado de visual **vb.net**. ¿Conoces de alguna librería o algo que pueda usar del lado de vb.net para poder utilizar el **Storage** de Firebase?

Comment: Encontre esta API que sirve para usar servicios de google, espero sea lo que estes buscando http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/vbnet.asp

Comment: He estado buscando, pero sigo creyendo que lo mas fácil seria hacer peticiones HTTP del lado de **vb.net** y configurar un servidor en **node.js** para que se encargue del resto, no es muy complicado y la documentación es clara. ¡Exitos en tu proyecto!